# CSS :hover formats table rows unpredictably in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm helping with an interactive table in a dashboard. Clicking rows in the table alters the data displayed on the rest of the dashboard. The table rows can have a  `'selected'` class, where the selected row is given a 4px bold border. The rows also have a `:hover` selector that gives them a 2px border.

My issue is that when using **Mozilla Firefox V 56.0.1** this causes the rows between the row being hovered over and the selected row to be given a 4px border on the left and right sides of the row. See below for details.

[Unintended behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLHAL.png)

[Intended behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgJOV.png)

Here is the code:

HTML and CSS in CodePen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOzJNZ

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tr.notselected:hover {
       border: 2px solid black;
       padding: 2px;
    }
    tr.selected {
       border: 4px solid black; }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2">Header 1</td>
        <td colspan="2">Header 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Subheader 1.1</td>
        <td>Subheader 1.2</td>
        <td>Subheader 2.1</td>
        <td>Subheader 2.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selected">
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td >10.1</td>
        <td >10.6</td>
        <td >9.1</td>
        <td >9.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>12.9</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
        <td>10.1</td>
        <td>10.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8.7</td>
        <td>8.8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>7.9</td>
        <td>7.9</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr><tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9.2</td>
        <td>8.4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="notselected">
       <td>Row 5</td>
       <td>12.2</td>
       <td>11.9</td>
       <td>7.3</td>
       <td>9.0</td>
     </tr>
         
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added following class in order to fix firefox issue:

```
tr.notselected {
      border: 0px solid black; 
   }
```

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tr.notselected:hover {
       border: 2px solid black;
       padding: 2px;
    }
    tr.selected {
       border: 4px solid black; 
   }
   tr.notselected:hover td {
   padding-bottom: 6px; }
   tr.notselected {
      border: 0px solid black; 
   }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2">Header 1</td>
        <td colspan="2">Header 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Subheader 1.1</td>
        <td>Subheader 1.2</td>
        <td>Subheader 2.1</td>
        <td>Subheader 2.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selected">
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td >10.1</td>
        <td >10.6</td>
        <td >9.1</td>
        <td >9.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>12.9</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
        <td>10.1</td>
        <td>10.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8.7</td>
        <td>8.8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>7.9</td>
        <td>7.9</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr><tr class="notselected">
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9.2</td>
        <td>8.4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="notselected">
       <td>Row 5</td>
       <td>12.2</td>
       <td>11.9</td>
       <td>7.3</td>
       <td>9.0</td>
     </tr>
         
    </table>
```